# How to convert Image type to Image<Bgr, Byte>?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

Any Idea how to convert `Image` type to `Image<Bgr, Byte>` type?

I get the image from `PictureBox` Control and I need to convert it to `Image<Bgr, Byte>` type.

```
Image pictureBoxImage = pictureBox.Image;
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = // ...
```

Comment: What are `Imgae`, `Bgr` and `Imgae< Bgr,Byte >`?

Comment: Can I suggest you read the documentation? http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_image_from_Bitmap):

> **Creating image from Bitmap**
>
> It is also possible to create an `Image<TColor, TDepth>` from a .Net
>   `Bitmap` object

So, you should be able to do:

```
var image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> IMG = new Image<Bgr, byte>((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
```

OR

```
var IMG = new Image<Bgr, byte>((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
```

Comment: `var`--as used in the accepted answer--is the preferred declaration for complex data types.

Answer (score 0):

For Emgu.CV 4.5 I had to add the Emgu.CV.Bitmap package and use `bitmap.ToImage<Bgr, byte>()`:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image))
{
    Image<Bgr, byte> image = bitmap.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
}
```